# How to extract Geojson Schema with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, geojson

I have a Geojson file and I want to extract the schema(structtype) correspondent with spark. Any help would be appreciated

**I use spark 2.3.1**

```
Geojson:
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiLineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              7.0847794888,
              50.7242091272
            ],
            [
              7.0859976701,
              50.7239505872
            ],
             ...
            [
              7.0946504307,
              50.722884129
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "strecke_id": 3,
        "auswertezeit": "2018-11-13T16:10:00",
        "geschwindigkeit": 26,
        "verkehrsstatus": "erh�hte Verkehrsbelastung"
      }
    },.....
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you post what you already tried. Did you try reading as spark.read.json("filePath").schema?

Comment: val data = spark.read.schema(newSchema).json("hdfs://........./file.json")

Comment: i try to read geojson data from hdfs(file.json) and to extract the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val data = spark.read.json("hdfs://........./file.json")
val schema = data.schema
```

This should give you the schema in StructType